# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/grpc/__init__.py'

Tags: python, grpc, sgx

I am using grpc in my app.py and I am going to run app.py inside SGX using Gramine, when I run command `gramine-sgx ./python app.py"` I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 844, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 980, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1037, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/grpc/__init__.py'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init_system()
apt_pkg.Error: E:Error reading the CPU table

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 844, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 980, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1037, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/grpc/__init__.py'
```

I checked the permissons of init.py and I even tried to run the code using sudo but the same error came up

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 82351 Dec 15 13:37 __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/grpc/ to trusted files in  manifest solved the issue.